# Maven Adding dependency for specific java package

Tags: java, maven

I have two version of the same jar file. (version 1 and 2). My problem is that i want classes in a specific package to use one version and classes in another package to use the other version.Both the packages are under the same maven project.

Tried to add both the jar files as dependencies in the POM, but the second entry overrides the first one and only one version is added as dependency.

Is there a way to achieve this in Maven.?

Comment: Good lord, why would you need this?

Comment: re-write the code so it only needs one

Comment: If you really nedd, check **osgi** concepts, loading multiple versions of jar files. You need multiple class loaders

Comment: @christopher can think of one reason someone'd want to try this, and it's a bogus reason. That's when there's a bug in v1 that's fixed in v2 but there's been major API changes between v1 and v2 that would require refactoring a lot of code in the application. It's of course bogus as there's good reason to do just that...

Comment: Some of our packages are not yet ready to move to the new version. So those packages are to be using the old version.

Comment: I would advice against this. I don't know the exact details but it seems like this is not exactly the standard way to handle libs. What is the main reason that you want to have this configuration for your project? Is there any other configuration that might work?

Comment: @pablo : We have a blackbox kind of thing which is used by different work flows. Now some flow is loosely coupled to the blackbox so that they can easily be changed to use the new version of blackbox, while some other are not that easy to change.

Answer (score 1):

Think about DLL Hell. The only way you can get various versions of the same class to coexist in a single JVM is to load each using a different class loader, and you don't want to go that way.

Rewrite your code so all of it works with the newest version of the library, or rewrite it so it doesn't need whatever changes in the library require you to use v2, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

*Token ugly solution...*

Split your project into two modules, where each module uses a different version of the dependency. To avoid the class-loader problems referenced in  jwenting's excellent answer, use the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to rename the dependency packages in one of the modules.

See [Relocating Classes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) for an example of doing this.